# Can I use collect or findAll to filter out nested maps?

Tags: groovy

This is my map I want to filter:

```
def myMap = [
'myMap':[
   // Collect keyOne
   "keyOne": [
           "fieldOne": "blah",
           "fieldTwo": "blah",
           "checkIfThisIsSetToTrue": true,
   ],
   // Do not collect keyTwo
   "keyTwo": [
           "fieldOne": "blah",
           "fieldTwo": "blah",
           "checkIfThisIsSetToTrue": false,
   ],
   // Do not collect keyThree
   "keyThree": [
           "fieldOne": "blah",
           "fieldTwo": "blah",
           //checkIfThisIsSetToTrue not set at all here
   ],
]]
```

I only want to return items where `checkIfThisIsSetToTrue == true`. `checkIfThisIsSetToTrue` could also be null as well.

I know I can loop over it like this and add items to a new map:

```
myMap.each { key, val ->
  if (val?.checkIfThisIsSetToTrue):
    ...
}
```

But I think using `collect` or `findAll` would be more succinct and groovy-ish.

I tried to filter it like this:

```
def myVar = myMap.findAll { it?.checkIfThisIsSetToTrue == true }
def myVar = myMap.any{ it?.checkIfThisIsSetToTrue == true }
def myVar = myMap.collect{ it?.checkIfThisIsSetToTrue == true }
```

But I get the error:

```
No such property: checkIfThisIsSetToTrue for class: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
def myMap = [
'myMap':[
   // Collect keyOne
   "keyOne": [
           "fieldOne": "blah",
           "fieldTwo": "blah",
           "checkIfThisIsSetToTrue": true,
   ],
   // Do not collect keyTwo
   "keyTwo": [
           "fieldOne": "blah",
           "fieldTwo": "blah",
           "checkIfThisIsSetToTrue": false,
   ],
   // Do not collect keyThree
   "keyThree": [
           "fieldOne": "blah",
           "fieldTwo": "blah",
           //checkIfThisIsSetToTrue not set at all here
   ],
]]

// unclear why there is a nested
// myMap in the sample but there is
def innerMyMap= myMap.myMap

def selectedMaps = innerMyMap.findAll {
    it.value.checkIfThisIsSetToTrue
}
```